# Proof of existence of a non-trivial character on a local field of positive characteristic

Tags: harmonic-analysis, characters, local-field

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a [local field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field).

> **Definition of local field:**
>
> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and a topological space. Then $\mathbb{K}$ is called a *locally compact field* if both $\mathbb{K}^+$ and $\mathbb{K}^*$ are locally compact Abelian groups, where $\mathbb{K}^+$ and $\mathbb{K}^*$ denote the additive and multiplicative groups of $\mathbb{K}$, respectively.
>
> a ***local field*** is a locally compact field with respect to a non-discrete topology.

How can I prove the existence of a non-trivial character $\chi$ on $\mathbb{K}$ ?

Comment: This is a straightforward consequence of Pontryagin duality.

Comment: please give More Explain.